# creditor textatea значение on change

Tags: javascript, post

```
$( 'textarea.editor' ).ckeditor({
    on: {
        change: function( evt ) {
            var name = this.name;
            var textarea = $('textarea[id="'+name+'"]');
            textarea.trigger( "change" );
        }
    }
});
```

Есть textarea с событием change и на нее подвешен ckeditor
После события почему-то значение получается не так, как нужно и код:

```
textarea.change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "edit.php",
            data: 'value='+value,
            success: function(msg){

            }
        });
    });
```

Не передает правильно значение. Передает только одну строчку, т.е в отладчике вместо

> value:
>
> Комплект защиты , синий/белый

Передается

> value=
>
> Комплект защиты , синий/белый

Comment: Я минуты 2-3 пялюсь и вижу, что результаты одинаковые.

Comment: Нет! в первом случае передает как POST в списке : param1 : 123, param2 : 321, value : <p>... А во втором - строкой параметров, похожей на GET param1=123&param2=321&value=<p>... И сохраняется в value значение до переноса строки при получении через POST

Comment: Так вы, отправляя POST-запрос, и оформляете его как query-строку, используя символ равенства: `data: 'value='+value`. Куда там взяться двоеточиям? И что вообще за велосипед вы изобретаете? Раз уж используете jQuery, то передавайте в параметр `data` либо JavaScript-объект, который сам затем сериализуется как надо, либо генерируйте тело POST-запроса самостоятельно, используя метод [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).